# Jira Agile: How to report by Epic, by Story/Parent, by Subtask?

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

I would like to get a summary report of my sprints and what happened with my tickets. I'd like to see aggregations by epic, then by story, with the leaf level being the subtickets on a story item.

Is there any way to do this? I Can get the particular sprint's information, but that's as far as I've gotten.

`project = "ADS Agile" AND assignee = MYNAME AND resolution in (Completed, Fixed, "Cannot Reproduce", Approved, "Won't Fix", Duplicate) AND sprint = 100 AND resolution = Completed ORDER BY summary ASC, key ASC`

//edit Example output;

`T   Key     Summary     Assignee    P   Status  Resolution  Created     Updated     Due      Time Spent  Original Estimate

Sub-task    AGILE-35

AGILE-30 (New) Decide whether to use existing system.
    Anne    Normal  Closed  Completed   01/12/15    01/15/15        2 hours     2 hours

Story   AGILE-31

As the PO of ss, I'd like tests for each path.
     Anne   Normal  Closed  Completed   01/05/15    01/29/15        1 week, 4 days, 1 minute    4 days, 4 hours`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to run the query you have now and then export it to Excel. You should be able to do the aggregation you want within Excel.

Comment: Well, the columns don't come out right. (Added output to question) The parent task is only differentiated by not having a parent shown, and the epic is never as far as I know available to be shown?

Comment: Try the full export (all columns). That should include the epic link field for the stories. Then you can sort on that and remove the columns you don't need.

Comment: sorry for such a late update, but the problem is that the parent of subtasks is identified by its list of subtasks (there's a column for that), but the subtasks have no link to their parent except in the story name. So it's a weird parsing problem I guess. Excel can do anything, so surely it could be done but I haven't spent the time.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal is it. I have generally only dealt with Epics and Stories. When you go to the sub-task level as well it is a real challenge. I suspect the only way to do this will be with a plugin that is designed for specifically this kind of reporting.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of query results, select the columns you want before exporting to .csv. Easier than eliminating from Excel.
Reorder and organize the columns as you wish before the export as well.
Then save the query so that it appears as you wish.

Jira will never display the stories -under- the epic, which is very frustrating. But displaying the name of the epic link will do the trick.

Realizing that the original poster certainly figured this out a year ago, but thinking that others might have the same question.

Comment: when selecting columns, doesn't that set the columns for all of your subsequent other queries?